# How to create aggregate query to dump mongo collection into solr

Tags: mongodb, solr, aggregate

I created a connection to dump a mongo collection into solr, however, I was wondering if there is any way I can create a query passing an aggregate.
Ex:

In my data-config.xml

```
<entity
        processor = "MongoEntityProcessor"
         query = "{total: {$ gte: 0}}"
         collection = "order"
         datasource = "test_development"
         transformer = "MongoMapperTransformer"
         name = "test">
```

Could I do that?

```
<entity
         processor = "MongoEntityProcessor"
         query = "aggregate([{$ project: {_id: 1, total: 1}}])"
         collection = "order"
         datasource = "test_development"
         transformer = "MongoMapperTransformer"
         name = "test">
```

Answer (score 0):

I and my Technical leader made a fork of a library in github that used only the find function of mongo, we adapted it to be able to put aggregation.

Follow GitHub with the library and documentation: https://github.com/GuilhermeViterboGalvao/solrMongoDBDataImporter

Simple Example:

```
<entity  
        processor="MongoDBEntityProcessor"        
        collection="myCollection"
        aggregationQuery="[ { '$project' :{ totalTime: 1, token: 1, statusCode: 1, requestId: 1, date: 1, month: { $month: '$date' }, day: { $dayOfMonth: '$date' }, hour: { $hour: '$date' } } } ]"
        datasource="MyMongoDBDataSourceName-service_development"
        transformer="ObjectIdToLongTransformer" 
        name="myEntityOfCollectionXXX">
```

You Put de aggregation query in tag "aggregationQuery" and execute data-import in solr cloud